# Java MTP library that works on Windows

Tags: java, android, windows, mtp

Does anybody know of a **working** Java MTP library for Windows? I'm trying to pull/push files into an Android device and I can't use adb. So far I've found [jMTP](http://code.google.com/p/jmtp/) and [jusbpmp](http://code.google.com/p/jusbpmp/) but neither of them work properly:

- jMTP successfully recognizes my Android devices but as of this writing there is no support for file transfer of any kind. All I've managed to do is go through the file system.
- jusbpmp is supposed to be able to but its awfully buggy and fails to recognize some of the devices I'm trying to develop for.

**Worst of all**: Both projects seem to be dead and buried.

Comment: Well I follow your path. I tryied that 2 library and both didn't work. Did you find an alternative solution ?

Comment: Why is this question not constructive? There is really no good library for MTP in Java. @P.Sohm, Did you find any good library?

Comment: that's far far away. i found a solution which worked but i'm sorry. I don't remember what lib I used and the project can't be found.